# Time complexity in C++

Tags: c++, vector, set, time-complexity

what is the time complexity of converting a vector into set in c++.
Can it can be done in O(n).

if i am copying vector into set like this,
**set s(v.begin(), v.end());**
then what is its time complexity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `O(N * log(N))` from the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set). It is linear if the vector is already sorted (also in the documentation).

You may be interested in `std::unordered_set`. It's constructor taking two iterators is `O(N)` on average [(see here)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/unordered_set).

Comment: @AlanBirtles Good point - I edited that into the answer.